# Starting of with the URLs in django blog

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

http://code.google.com/p/django-threadedcomments/,I have integrated the the following Blog APP with my site.In the URLs.py i have the following below,My question is that what is the first link that i have to start of with..

```
  from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
  from threadedcomments.models import FreeThreadedComment
  import views

  free = {'model' : FreeThreadedComment}

  urlpatterns = patterns('',
      ### Comments ###
      url(r'^comment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', views.comment, name="tc_comment"),
      url(r'^comment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/$', views.comment, name="tc_comment_parent"),
      url(r'^comment/(?P<object_id>\d+)/delete/$', views.comment_delete, name="tc_comment_delete"),
      url(r'^comment/(?P<edit_id>\d+)/edit/$', views.comment, name="tc_comment_edit"),

      ### Comments (AJAX) ###
      url(r'^comment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<ajax>json|xml)/$', views.comment, name="tc_comment_ajax"),
      url(r'^comment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/(?P<ajax>json|xml)/$', views.comment, name="tc_comment_parent_ajax"),
      url(r'^comment/(?P<edit_id>\d+)/edit/(?P<ajax>json|xml)/$', views.comment, name="tc_comment_edit_ajax"),

      ### Free Comments ###
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', views.free_comment, name="tc_free_comment"),
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/$', views.free_comment, name="tc_free_comment_parent"),
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<object_id>\d+)/delete/$', views.comment_delete, free, name="tc_free_comment_delete"),
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<edit_id>\d+)/edit/$', views.free_comment, name="tc_free_comment_edit"),

      ### Free Comments (AJAX) ###
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<ajax>json|xml)/$', views.free_comment, name="tc_free_comment_ajax"),
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<content_type>\d+)/(?P<object_id>\d+)/(?P<parent_id>\d+)/(?P<ajax>json|xml)/$', views.free_comment, name="tc_free_comment_parent_ajax"),
      url(r'^freecomment/(?P<edit_id>\d+)/edit/(?P<ajax>json|xml)/$', views.free_comment, name="tc_free_comment_edit_ajax"),
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django threadedcomments isn't a blog app, its a threaded comments app.

```
#######################
django-threadedcomments
#######################

Django-threadedcomments is a simple yet flexible threaded commenting system for
Django. What it means to say that they are *threaded* is that commenters can
reply not only to the original item, but to other comments as well. It becomes
near-trivial to create a system similar to what Reddit or Digg have in their
comments sections.
```

There is no "starting page", you just use the threaded comments tags in pages to add comments to model instances.

Comment: The template in the threaded comments app are used to display the comments on your pages. They are used when you use the threaded comments template tags. If you are looking for a blog app check out http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/